# Laravel Eloquent filter on children

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got the following relationship:

Customers
-> hasMany (Contracts)

Now I want to get all customers including all contracts that have a given condition:

```
$c = Customer::with('contracts','contracts.service','contracts.contractpos')
    ->whereHas('contracts', function ($query) {
        $query
        ->where('invoice_next','=',$this->invoice_next)
        ->groupBy('customer_id');
    })
    ->orderBy('company')
    ->get();
```

However, I get all customers that have a contract fullfilling the condition (invoice_next = $this->invoice.next ), but also all the contracts that doesn't match the condition.

So filtering the customers works, but I then get all of the customers contracts instead of only the ones that are due. Where do I make the mistake?

It seems like the "where" condition in the subquery only works for the customers but doesn't filter the children (contracts).

Thanks for any hint in the right direction.

Greetings
eXe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$c = Customer::with(['contracts' => function($query){
          $query->where('invoice_next','=',$this->invoice_next)
          ->with(['service', 'contractpos'])
          ->groupBy('customer_id');
     }])
    ->whereHas('contracts', function ($query) {
        $query->where('invoice_next','=',$this->invoice_next);            
    })
    ->orderBy('company')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hi. Same result set. It seems like its filtering the customers correctly, but if one of the contract is valid he just returns all contracts of that given customer.

Comment: Amazing! I only had to remove the ->groupBy because it throw an error. But that wasn't needed anyway because of the eloquent model. Thank you very much!